# Debugging an ASP.NET application on Local IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I have setup a local IIS instance to run and development an older ASP.NET (CLR v4.0) application that I have inherited.

I am running it an a virtual directory, and I am able to attach to the IIS process and debug it (annoying).  However, I am unable to "F5" in Visual Studio to start debugging.  I get an error message saying "The web server could not find the requested resource."

I have went through all of the Microsoft advice on their help page without much luck.  Am I naive in thinking that this will work, or am I missing something?  I even installed the IIS 6 Metabase compatibility, but that did not seem to help either.

I realize that I probably need to give more information, but I don't know what other details I need to add.

This is running on Windows 8.1 Enterprise with IIS 8, and I am using Visual Studio Professional.
Thanks

Comment: I will note that the IIS logs are fairly unhelpful.  However, I believe that I am seeing a 404 in the log.

2015-03-26 23:54:26 ::1 DEBUG /App/DebugAttach.aspx - 80 - ::1 - - 404 6 0 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MYSTERY SOLVED!!!!!!!!!

Apparently, Request filtering is installed by default.  In order for debugging to work, you have to go the virtual directory -> Request filtering -> Http Verbs, and allow verb DEBUG.